# How can I successfully implement my embedded HTML including external js into webbrowser object?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

If i run the below in a normal browser window it works fine, but from within a webbrowser object it fails to run the script. Please help:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="377" data-height="250" href="https://twitter.com/KhaosERP?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by KhaosERP</a>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If that Html is contained in a file, IIRC IE, by default, disables scripts run from a local File. You can enable the feature but this requires a restart of the machine (or, possibly, a registry update + broadcast the notification). On a user machine, the consequence of this restriction is something to evaluate. A third-party WebBrowser control, in this case, is a choice to consider, IMO.

Comment: Hi @Jimi Thank you so much for taking the time to comment. I used Gecko45 webbrowser control and it loads perfectly for 5 seconds until I get aSystem.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' on static void main of program.cs ...Application.Run(new Form1());
Any ideas?

Comment: The apparent *jump* to `Application.Run(new Form1());` is just caused by the unhandled exception that bubbled up. You have an error somewhere in your code (an Invalid Cast, apparently). Make another question, showing the code that generates the exception. Add these lines in your Program.cs, right after void Main(): `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);` `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnHandledException);`.

Comment: Then, as the last line: `public static void OnUnHandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An unhandled exception has been rised\r\n" + 
                    "Error Object: " + e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject);
}`

Comment: Thanks again Jimi.
I've added your suggestion and the same results appear. Forgive my inexperience but what should I be seeing? I expect the above allows a more targeted diagnosis of the problem, how do i access it?

Comment: That code simply adds a *global* handler for unhandled exceptions. You should see (if correctly implemented) a MessageBox that shows you the current stack trace. Then the code should resume where the exception has been raised. Of course I'm not sure where/when this exception is generated. This is why I suggested to post your code in a new question.

Comment: I've copied my whole sln to the below. It will need the Geckofx45 package installing seperately. If you have the time, i would be endlessly grateful.

https://github.com/cswanne/KCHealthCheck

Comment: There was just a library bitness incompatibility (GeckoFx-Core not working on 32bit). I've updated the Gecko Control to version 60.22 (32bit as it was before). I've also removed the user32 references (SendMessage and ReleaseCapture). They're not needed. The borderless Form is moved using standard events. [Full package on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O7_6Jz_aQanmrkKrUw5LP_Kc3WVc6CHW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Jimi, you sir are an absolute legend! Thank you so much for this. I cant thank you enough. Works perfectly. Thank you :)

Comment: Note that I've left there the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`. This, as it is, can be good while debugging or even at run-time. But if you leave it there, you should use it to **handle** the exceptions, not to eat them up. When you compile for release, you can't have a `Console.WriteLine()` thing. This could crash your app. Either log the unhandled exceptions, message the user or remove it completely.